# VPN Setup On Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

Long story short, I have the work old Cisco PCF file and have been asked to make it work with my new test Windows 8.1 work machine (without running any Cisco client), ie: using the internal Windows 8.1 VPN software.

I have no idea about VPN's... but here is a list of the items in the PCF file. Can someone please help me to work out what setting goes where!

```
Host
AuthType
GroupName
enc_GroupPwd
EnableISPConnect
ISPConnectType
ISPConnect
BackupServer
EnableMSLogon
CertSerialHash
DHGroup
PeerTimeout
TcpTunnelingPort
```

There are more entries in the PCF file, but they have no values against them.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can't use a PCF-file direct with Windows 8.1s internat VPN-setup, but you can use it with the freeware from [Shrew Net](https://www.shrew.net/download/vpn).

How to set it up you can find [here](http://ithelp.port.ac.uk/getattachment.php?data=MjE0fEZvciBXaW5kb3dzIDggVlBOIFVzZXJzICgxKS5kb2N4).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.